# How to get Angle data from AX-12 Servo

Tags: ros, servo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS fans..

I try to make a node that read angle position of AX-12 Servo.. I move manually the motor servo and then the node read the servo's position..

How do I get servo's position ?? I hope someone can help me.. Thanks  ^_^

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60752/how-to-get-angle-data-from-ax-12-servo/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not think you need to create a node like this yourself. Check out the [dynamixel package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/dynamixel_motor)
This should do the job for you

---

Originally posted by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) with karma: 1554 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-04-15**:
thanks @kalectro